# Responses to the study questions from Causal Inference in Statistics (by Judea Pearl).

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, causal-diagrams, causality

Does anybody know a source where the correct answers to study questions from the mentioned book are described?

I would like to validate whether my way of thinking is correct.
I have found only two questions on the forum while in the book there are many more.

Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: From twitter: https://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1032807139553697793, bottom of page, suggests that you might be able to contact his assistant.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please paste it as a response, so that I can accept it to make it visible as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from a comment.

From [his twitter](http://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1032807139553697793), bottom of page, suggests that you might be able to contact his assistant.